# Editing polygons simultaneously in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, editing, topology

I have two polygons:

[image]

How can I reshape both Polygon 1 and Polygon 2 at the same time?

Will the area of each polygon change automatically in the table after reshaping?

I'm using ArcMap 10.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume that you are trying to do this on two polygons in the same feature class of a geodatabase.

I tested using a file geodatabase but other flavours should work fine too.

Shapefiles will not have their areas updated automatically but geodatabase feature classes do.

What you want to do is easy using [Map Topology](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01mm0000000r000000) at any license level of ArcGIS for Desktop.

1. Start editing your polygon feature class
2. On the Topology toolbar use the Select Topology button to make your map topology
3. On the Topology toolbar use the Topology Edit Tool to choose the edge between polygons 1 and 2.
4. On the Topology toolbar use the Modify Edge tool (which opens the Edit Vertices) toolbar
5. Use the Edit Vertices toolbar to Add and Move vertices along that shared edge
6. Click F2 to finish the sketch

If you have the attribute table open while doing the edit you will see the areas of both polygons change at step 6.