# Widening Multiple Polygons at same time in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing

I am trying to edit polygons in the same feature class. I have a feature class which contain a number of polygons. I will need to increase the size of the polygons but only the width (the length has to remain). The polygons are not perfect rectangles thus making it a bit harder to edit as well.

I am wondering if I can do this using geoprocessing tools or DIE to edit the polygons at the sametime thus I do not have to edit the polygons one by one. I have quite a number of polygons to edit. If I have a tool to run or something the results will be more consistent compared to editing by hard.

Or I am wondering if it is possible to add a polygon on top of the original polygon with the same length but larger width.

Example:

[image]

The edited polygon should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Initially I though this sounded like shared geometry editing for which map topology might be the solution (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131654/editing-polygons-simultaneously-in-arcmap).  However, reading it again I think you want to select lots of rectangular polygons on many different angles and say "increase the width of every one of them by X meters".  For that to be doable I think you would have to guarantee that every selected polygon is a perfect rectangle.

Comment: Also, from your pictures the widening does not seem to be symmetrical about the mid-axis - should it be?

Comment: if  widening is symmetrical, you should write some python code to achieve your goal. I don't know of any ready tool (Geoprocessing or editing) that does it for you.

Comment: All the polygons are not exactly of the same size but I will be adding the same width to all the polygons. How do I do this in Python? The widening should be symmetrical, I didn't do a good job in editing as I am editing it manually.

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to improve it with the clarifications that we have been seeking here via comments, please?  Can you guarantee that the original polygons are perfect rectangles?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the size of a shape layer by editing the vertices of the shape.  To do this you’ll want to click the “edit” tool on the “editor” toolbar.
Then click Edit Vertices.  All the vertices of the shape will show up and you will be able to move them to where you would like.
Additionally, you will be able to add and subtract vertices within the editor toolbar as well.